# Using SKScene as a loading screen

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skscene

In my game I am making, I wanted to make an animation every time the game is opened. I was thinking of using an SKScene as my loading scene to be able to show the animation. Do you think this is a good idea or is there a better way to go about going this?

Comment: Implement it. Does it work? Yes. Good. Don't get held up in analysis paralysis over such a trivial thing. ;)

Answer (score -1):

SKScenes are the building blocks for Sprite Kit.  You can animate, delay and transition to another scene using the functionality scenes have built in.  Basically, make a sequence that ends with the scene transitioning to the next scene.

```
// Here is transitioning code which covers a majority of your tasks.

SKTransition *reveal = [SKTransition flipHorizontalWithDuration:0.5];
SKScene * gameOverScene = [[GameOverScene alloc] initWithSize:self.size won:YES];
[self.view presentScene:gameOverScene transition: reveal];
```